# how to create one logger for 100 class

Tags: java, log4j

I want to write a logger for my project . log file for single class is 
Ok . log for  multiple classes seems problem to me .  I do not want to 
allocate  one logger for one class , 10 logger for 10 class. I want to 
some other smart way .means i want to one logger for all classs

how to call one  logger for multiple classs

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have multiple logger instances is because you want them to behave *different* when logging (usually by printing out the class name they are configured with).  If you do not care about that, you can just create a single static logger instance in a class and use that all over the place.

If so you will most likely want to configure the logger framework you use, so it prints out where the logging line is, so you have at least *some* idea where the log statement generating what you see is located.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a single logger for all classes is **not recommended** by log4j as this hinders your ability to configure each logger separately, but best practices aside. There are two ways to accomplish this task. The first is to create a static utility logging class. This example is incomplete but demonstrates how you would go about defining a logging utilities class.

```
public final class LoggingUtils{

    private LoggingUtils(){}

    public static void log(String message){
        //Log message
    }
}
```

Another way you could achieve this is create a single, static logger instance and then call the logging methods on that object from all the classes in your project. `public static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a static utility logging class to be single point logger,so if we need to change the logger package, you will only update this class.

```
final public class Logger {
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("Log");

    enum Level {Error, Warn, Fatal, Info, Debug}

    private Logger() {/* do nothing */};

    public static void logError(Class clazz, String msg) {
        log(Level.Error, clazz, msg, null);
    }

    public static void logWarn(Class clazz, String msg) {
        log(Level.Warn, clazz, msg, null);
    }

    public static void logFatal(Class clazz, String msg) {
        log(Level.Fatal, clazz, msg, null);
    }

    public static void logInfo(Class clazz, String msg) {
        log(Level.Info, clazz, msg, null);
    }

    public static void logDebug(Class clazz, String msg) {
        log(Level.Debug, clazz, msg, null);
    }


    public static void logError(Class clazz, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        log(Level.Error, clazz, msg, throwable);
    }


    public static void logWarn(Class clazz, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        log(Level.Warn, clazz, msg, throwable);
    }

    public static void logFatal(Class clazz, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        log(Level.Fatal, clazz, msg, throwable);
    }

    public static void logInfo(Class clazz, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        log(Level.Info, clazz, msg, throwable);
    }

    public static void logDebug(Class clazz, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        log(Level.Debug, clazz, msg, throwable);
    }

    private static void log(Level level, Class clazz, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        String message = String.format("[%s] : %s", clazz, msg);
        switch (level) {
            case Info:
                logger.info(message, throwable);
                break;
            case Warn:
                logger.warn(message, throwable);
                break;
            case Error:
                logger.error(message, throwable);
                break;
            case Fatal:
                logger.fatal(message, throwable);
                break;
            default:
            case Debug:
                logger.debug(message, throwable);
        }
    }

}
```